# Knockout wizard with Asp.net MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I have a wizard like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/FyuSD/ when I click button next data of current step are send to the server (the function to send data its not display in this link ) in the server i have an action like this:

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SocialNetworkChoice(string[] selectedSocialNetwork)
    {
        if (selectedProduct!= null)
        {
          // check if the user got a social account linked in for 
          // all the selected networks and redirect to the link account page
          ....
            if (q.Count() > 0)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("LinkAccount", "Account",
                         new LinkAccountModel() { ProviderName = q.First() });
            }

            else
            {....}
         }
    }
```

**Knockout:**

```
    <script id="socNetchoiceTmpl" type="text/html">         
       <ul data-bind="foreach: socialNetworksList, visible:
                  socialNetworksList().length > 0">
          <li>
             <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: $data, checked:  
                 $parent.selectedSocialNetworks" /><span data-bind="text: $data"/>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </script>


   function SocialNetChoicesViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.socialNetworksList = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.selectedSocialNetworks = ko.observableArray([]);

     self.save = function () {
        $.ajax("/Home/SocialNetworkChoice", {
            data: ko.toJSON({ selectedSocialNetworks: self.selectedSocialNetworks }),
            type: "post", contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.Success) {
                    //alert(result.Message);
                }
                else {
                    alert(result.Message);
                }
            }
        });
     };
     // Load initial state from server, convert it to Task instances,
     //  then populate self.tasks
     $.getJSON("/Home/SocialNetworkChoice", function (allData) {
        var mappedItems = $.map(allData, function (item) { return item });
        self.socialNetworksList(mappedItems);
    });
   };
```

in the first step i have two checkbox for two social networks, when a user check ckeckbox data its send to the action SocialNetworkChoice.
if (q.Count() > 0) the view for action "LinkAccount" doesn't display and the wizard pass to the second step

How can to solve this probleme if (q.Count() > 0) redirect to LinkAccount (View) else to second step

I'm sorry for my bad english,

thanks,

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with knockout.. which piece of code in Javascript calls your controller?

Comment: @ikh when I click button next function save its called

Answer (score 0):

Your are only redirecting the ajax call, not the visible page.

One solution is to detect the redirected ajax call and programmatically redirect the page accordingly. E.g. set window.location from javascript.